# Text Field Validation vs Prevention

Tags: usability, forms, validation, user-expectation, error-prevention

I've been having a debate (mostly with myself) over the best approach to deal with invalid input in text fields -- validation versus prevention.

Taking a  numeric text field as an example, is it better to prevent the entry of non-numeric characters (allowing for special cases like sign, decimal pt., etc.) or allow the entry of whatever and then indicate an error message (typically when focus is left) if the result is invalid?

The first approach is "don't allow the user to do something you know is wrong" but has the disadvantage that it may not be at all obvious what is going on if a keyboard key is typed and nothing happens.  It also breaks the expectation that, if you type something in a text field, you expect to see what you typed.

In the past, I've generally leaned towards the prevention approach but in general but feel perhaps, at the field input-level, the validation approach provides a better user experience.  Is anyone aware of a best practice here?

Comment: With prevention, you also might have to deal with pasted values. There are multiple ways to handle this but it's just extra logic that you have to remember to do.

Comment: @SunnySydeUp makes a good point, to expand from my point of view: If you want for example a loyalty card number no spaces, I might have it stored with spaces (e.g. on the email your site just sent me!), paste it in, then edit out the spaces - a form that doesn't let me do this, or stops me leaving the field until I've fixed it (not seen on the web but offline) is seriously offputting.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone!  Looks like you all pretty much agree with what I've been feeling.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Prevention will likely frustrate a user as they are entering it and it isn't working.  Of course this can be fixed with adequate messaging that lets them know why certain characters were rejected.

Some users may also be typing with their heads down and may not see when some characters are rejected. If they are typing 10 characters but only a few within those keystrokes are rejected, they may never know since their head is down.

In general I have preferred validation as it allowed the user to see their error. As you get more complex inputs it may become more difficult for users to understand why some characters are rejected.

Comment: I go with the validation also because we may have complex pattern that we cannot prevent the user from entering but can be easier validated

Comment: Personally I find it exceedingly frustrating when I type in, say, a phone number, only to have the submission rejected for "hyphens not allowed". Sheesh, if they aren't allowed, just ignore them when I'm typing. Of course, the better answer is to accept them, and silently strip them out on the server side.

Comment: For numeric inputs where you only allow a certain level of precision (decimals), I also feel there is a good argument to make for automatically rounding the user's input on blur without turning things red and getting in the user's face about it.

Answer (score 13):

Preventing the user from doing something that you know is wrong is *never about preventing keystrokes in a text box*. It is about removing the need for typing altogether if possible for that particular input.

For example:

- Don't validate dates in a text box, get rid of the text entry and use a date picker control.
- Have a set number of standard options where the user picks one? Let the user select them from a dropdown / list instead of typing. If you need to give free text entry in addition to this list, use an "other" option and only then allow text entry.

There are many different data entry controls available that are not text boxes. Make sure you consider all your options before plumping for text entry.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Way to take a step back. I kinda got lost in the weeds ha

Comment: @Franchesca: Correct, of course -- don't use a text box unless necessary.  My particular consideration was numeric input of arbitrary amounts -- not something that could be picked from a list.

Comment: I cringe every time a web site forces good typists to reach for the mouse and navigate a clunky date picker. A sequence of precision mouse clicks is a lot more difficult than typing a few numbers. The same goes for drop downs unless they allow me to navigate by typing.

Comment: @ThisIsTheDave I know, but it really depends who you are designing for. I wouldn't force the screen traders at our company to use date pickers, as they like to do *everything* by keyboard. However, if you are a travel website that grandma uses once a year to book a holiday, you might not focus on this.

Answer (score 10):

There are 3 common solutions to this problem, and depending on your specific use case, a balance of 2 or 3 of them is most likely the best.

As a rule of thumb...
**give feedback early and often**

---

You can provide the user with feedback:

**Before input**

Writing succinct, communicative copy is a solid step *before*. Tooltips, onboarding flows for first-time users, and other tools are at your disposal as well.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbMceE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

---

**During input**

Checking content dynamically *during* input and providing feedback is equally valuable. In your case, if you'd prefer to accept keystrokes, alert the user immediately. Additionally, like with the social security # or a credit card, you can automatically advance users to the next field (helping them group). With more "complicated" inputs, like an email, check the semantics for a match as soon as possible.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXKBdG.png)</sup>

---

**After input**

Validating content *after* a submission is typically the most frustrating for users because they've expended the most effort. If they went through the trouble to complete a form incorrectly, they're doing repeating trivial actions that don't provide value. Telling users they did something incorrectly is detrimental to the sentiment towards a product, and that's magnified by the amount of effort expended.

In the example below, the notification that the form was filled out incorrectly could have occurred before or during the input, rather than at the end of a series of actions.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdXarQ.png)</sup>

---

I would discourage you from disallowing certain keystrokes, but if the copy and feedback are clear, you can avoid the headache altogether the overwhelming majority of cases.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't** prevent (some) keystrokes as that could easily confuse and frustrate the user.

**Do** provide a clear label to tell the user up-front what type of input would be valid.

**Do** provide as-you-type validation feedback to guide the user if they have entered an invalid value.

Others have suggested not allowing keystrokes at all for dates and numeric fields. The may be appropriate in some situations, but in many (most?) situations it's often quicker for users to be able to navigate a form / interface using only the keyboard, especially if it's something they use regularly. So, if you go down this route then bear this in mind and maybe include keyboard navigation in whatever interface you provide. However, it may be simplest to just allow normal keyboard input with the suggestions above and then consider offering an additional way to select values (e.g. date picker, drop-down list etc.) as a "shortcut" for those who would prefer to use a mouse / pointer / touch interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely disagree with many of the answers already provided here.  We should generally be forthright about manipulations we do that would surprise a user.  But to address the actual example provided (an `input` field for entering numbers), **the W3 spec is opinionated in favor of silently rejecting non-numerical entries**.

The very first line of the [the MDN Web Docs article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) calls this out:

> `<input>` elements of type **number** are used to let the user enter a
> number. They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical
> entries.

If you take a second to play with the example provided in the article itself, you'll see that the input does not respond when the user types any characters besides numerical ones and a single decimal.

Obviously it's possible to work around this by using an `input` element where `type="text"`, but right out the gate, if we're following [Jakob's law](https://lawsofux.com/jakobs-law/), I think the right approach is to avoid needless complication and simply ignore it when users type letters in an input where there really only ever should be numbers.